# how to upsert a mongodb document/record with self generated _id in multiple thread scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, concurrency, upsert

I used mongodb in a scenario with many threads may insert/update the document/record in DB。_id is constructed by combining fields among all to be inserted as or updated against the document identified by _id. I used java code like below. I expected in multiple threads scenario, if the record/document is not exists, any thread can insert a new record/document with _id and thread specific cols/fields, after record is available, any thread can update their thread specific cols/fields. But in test, if the record is already available, error will be reported against duplicated _id is already available, but i only put _id in Filter other than in document to set. To resolve this i have to either add a distributed lock(redis) or catch the _id duplicated exception and update with upsert set to false, but either of these 2 are not so neat and clean and both have serious performance impact more than 100 ms. Any expert on mongodb can help me with this?

```
String rkValue = (String) newObjFromRow;
Bson rkFilter = Filters.eq(rkName, rkValue);
Document document = MyMongoRow.toDocument(row, groupByGuidTsList, groupByGuidTsIndexList);
Document wrappedUpdate = new Document();
wrappedUpdate.put("$set", updateDoc);
updateOneDocWNCompare(rkFilter, MongodbConstants.methodSetOnInsert, document, true);
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions();
options.upsert(true);
collection.updateOne(rkFilter, wrappedUpdate, options);
```

Comment: Of top of my head is to either use batch or synchronize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, anton, I also used redis/hbase a lot. for these kv style DB, my problem doesn’t exist at all, there is no insert concept for these DB. batch is not applicable in my case as each event requires immediate handl. and sychronize is for concurrency in same process, threads in my case are distributed in different hosts, so distributed lock is used

Comment: Well there must be some sort of synchronization somewhere. But anyway, is there any problem with concurrent upserts?

Comment: If document/record already exists, error will be reported that duplicated _id already exists

Comment: But you think it would happen or it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is somehow desired behavior if you check

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20380

So to deal with that, either introduce synchronization (even distributed on) or retry upsert atempt on error.

Comment: it is happening, if before app started, the record/document exists, no problem at all. _id conflicts exception happens when no this record/document corresponding to the specific _id value, and multiple threads call update with filter with_id and upsert is set to true

Comment: I can’t open the mongodb ticket you shared, maybe logged in required and I have no account, would you pls share a screen copy

Comment: I don't understand your first comment besides that "is happening" . But anyway, just redo the operation and it should succeed as update.

Comment: Im putting aside that you will have no clue which version of updated document you will be dealing with, but that another problem.